# Алгоритм деления точки эллиптической кривой Secp256k1 на число(скаляр)

Tags: python, математика, криптография, mathematica

Как реализовать алгоритм деления на число Z (скаляр) точки, лежащей на эллиптической кривой?

Кривая вида: y^2 = x^3 + A * x + B

A, B и число Z известны.

Точка произвольная, лежащая на кривой. Операции выполняются в кольце вычетов.
Более детально:

В случае рассмотрения ЭК над конечном полем, алгоритм деления точки на 2 можно реализовать следующим образом:

ЭК – y^2=x^3+ax+b над полем GF(P),

n – количество точек (включая точку на бесконечности),

P и n – простые числа,

Q – точка на эллиптической кривой, которую необходимо поделить на 2,

W – точка на эллиптической кривой, которую получится в результате, деления Q на 2.

Алгоритм:

Q/2 = W --> W ≡ Q * (2^(-1))(mod n) то есть надо умножать Q на мультипликативно обратное число (inverse) по модулю.

Для 2 inverse (2^(-1)) (mod n) – это тоже самое, что ((n-1)/2)+1.

W ≡ Q * (((n-1)/2)+1)(mod n)

Для любого другого числа r:

W ≡ Q * (r^(-1) mod n)

написал код на python, но вместо деления на 2 точка умножается
Результат деления точки на 2:

x=0xe493dbf1c10d80f3581e4904930b1404cc6c13900ee0758474fa94abe8c4cd13
y=0x51ed993ea0d455b75642e2098ea51448d967ae33bfbdfe40cfe97bdc47739922
а должно получится
x=0x79be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798
y=0x483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8

помогите добиться что-бы скрипт делил точку, а не умножал, совсем запутался уже.

```
# Координаты точки на кривой Secp256k1
x = 0xc6047f9441ed7d6d3045406e95c07cd85c778e4b8cef3ca7abac09b95c709ee5
y = 0x1ae168fea63dc339a3c58419466ceaeef7f632653266d0e1236431a950cfe52a

# Коэффициенты кривой Secp256k1
# n = 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141
p = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F
a = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
b = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007

# Функция для деления точки на 2
def divide_point_by_2(x, y, p, a, b):
    # Вычисление модулярного обратного элемента
    def mod_inverse(n, p):
        return pow(n, p-2, p)

    # Вычисление коэффициента наклона
    s = (3 * pow(x, 2) + a) * mod_inverse(2 * y, p) % p

    # Вычисление новых координат точки
    xr = (pow(s, 2) - 2 * x) % p
    yr = (s * (x - xr) - y) % p

    return xr, yr

# Деление точки на 2
xr, yr = divide_point_by_2(x, y, p, a, b)

# Вывод результатов
print("Результат деления точки на 2:")
print("x =", hex(xr))
print("y =", hex(yr))
```

Comment: Деление на скаляр - это умножение на число, инвертированное по модулю N, где N - порядок группы secp256k1 (`2^256−2^32−977`)

Comment: Значит ваша точка Q(x,y), не четная

Comment: Был ранее такой же вопрос на stackexchange: [ссылка 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601156/elliptic-curve-point-division) [ссылка 2](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/82129/how-to-divide-2-coordinates-on-elliptic-curve)